# NodeJS Express - How to Create Configuration File for POST Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, configuration, configuration-files

I using Express in NodeJS to accept `URL POST Request Call` then the system will response a `JSON File` upon Request. My current implementation is in a **Hardcode** method, as whenever I want to add more `POST Request Input` and define which `JSON File` to be read I will need to manually add on more `code` such as `if-else` statement in the `Javascript File`.

**My Desire Output:**

Is it possible to make create a Configuration File with JSON or YAML where allow user to edit the Configuration File whenever they wanted to add in more `Post Request Input` and add in more condition for which `JSON File` to be open instead of manually add on more code to the `Javascript File`?

My motive is to allow user to have a easy modification without touching the implementation code in the `Javascript File` itself but they just have to deal with the Configuration File instead.

**Hardcode Method:** (UPDATED)

```
const postConfig = require( "./config/postConfig" )

// before allow configuration, the code is
// app.post('/api',function (req, res, next)
// after configuration, I just need to change the value in postConfig.json to determine the POST URL.
app.post(postConfig.URL,function (req, res, next) {

    // HARDCODE AREA - The POST Request Input
    // What I want is make this 'userID' is configurable/changable using JSON file. 
    // Which mean its value will based on the value at JSON file. But not HARDCODE it as 'userID'. 
    // If I want to change to 'foodID', I just change it at JSON file.
    var input = req.body.userID,


  // HARDCODE AREA - ALL OF THE IF ELSE Statement
  if(input =="1"){

    var contents = fs.readFileSync(publicdir+"/api/a.json");
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
    res.send(jsonContent);

  }else if(input =="2"){

    var contents = fs.readFileSync(publicdir+"/api/b.json");
    var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
    res.send(jsonContent);

  }else{
    res.status(404);
    res.json({
        error: {
            code: 404  + " - Invalid ID"
        }
    });
  }


});
```

**postConfig.json:**

```
// This allow configuration for the POST URL
{
  // I can change to 
  // "URL" : "/api" or any value i want
  "URL" : "/plus" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a map for example:

```
var testMap = {
   1 : "a",
   2 : "b",
   3 : "c"
}
```

and use this map(can also be used as a separate JSON file) instead of if else statements

```
var checkJSONFile = testMap[user.userID];
if(checkJSONFile){
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(publicdir+"/api/"+checkJSONFile+".json");
  var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
  res.send(jsonContent);
}else{
  res.status(404);
  res.json({
    error: {
      code: 404  + " - Invalid ID"
    }
  });
}
```

Update:

```
var userId = req.body.userID;
req.body[<key_from_json>] = userId;
// Rest of the code follows
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done but it will only fetch the endpoints from the file when the server is restarted.

Comment: would you willing to update your code solution for better clarification? maybe it is the implementation i looking for.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "POST input (userID) become configurable"?

Comment: I have updated the code, mark as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: please undo your answer solution back to your 1st answer, forget about what I mentioned in comment. I have UPDATE my question and write comment at my code to explain what I want clearly. Please check out my Question again, you will understand. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot dynamically change keys in Ajax request by the client because that part is handled by the client not server but if you really want the keys according to your requirements then i will add an update to the answer.

Comment: The code req.body[<key_from_json>] = userId; seem like not working, but you help a lot, so i will accept your answer. If you could find any alternative solution to make the POST INPUT become dynamic which can be changed, Please share with me, i willing to give an up vote again. Thanks.